# R - Test for homogeneity of regression slopes results in singular model

Tags: r, heteroscedasticity, error, assumptions, ancova

I am trying to check the assumptions of a two-way ANCOVA. 
So in my model I have

- two factors (F1, F2)
- one dummy coded two level covariate (C)
- one dependent variable (D)

In order to check the assumption of homogeneity of regression slopes I tried
to perform an ANOVA with type 3 sums for the model D ~ F1*F2*C to see whether any
interactions with the covariate might be significant.
Using the Anova function from the car package this corresponds to

```
modd<-aov(D~F1*F2*C)
Anova(modd,type=3)
```

However, I encounter the following Error message:

```
Error in Anova.III.lm(mod, error, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
 there are aliased coefficients in the model
```

My question is, whether it makes sense for the homogeneity test to force R to compute the
ANOVA anyway by supplying the singular.ok=T option or what else I should do in order to 
check the assumption.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since C is a dummy variable with 2 levels, it really is like a factor, and your data is then a 3-factor experiment. Since there is singularity, it means that some of the cells (combinations of F1, F2, and C) are not represented in the data. Use the `table` function to find out which combinations have zero frequency, and maybe that can help you decide what might be a simpler model. And/or look at `coef(modd)` and see which coefficients are `NA`, corresponding to predictors that were thrown out.

Thinking about C as a covariate rather than a factor may just be adding confusion.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer - I do now use a combination of the functions coef and drop1 in order to identify which interactions can be savely omitted before computing the ANOVA - this works in most instances except for some cases, where drop1 leads to NA results for the F- and p values, which probably means that there are not enough data points for the covariate.